# flot dates sometimes uses two rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, flot

I just recently started with the flot library for displaying charts but when checking if different browsers shows everything correct I noticed something. When using IE everthing looks ok or atleast everything is on two rows, month on first row and date on second. Then I switched to firefox and depending on which chart and which month it showed different. In chrome it was the same as firefox but not on the same charts. Kinda hard to explain so I will provide an image below. What might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: Im using version 0.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine there's just slight differences with each browser producing more/less room on the xaxis and sometimes forcing the line wrap.  If you always want it to wrap, then set this explicitly in your options:

```
    $.plot('#placeholder', data, {
        xaxis: {
            mode: 'time',
            timeformat: '%b<br/>%d'
        }
    });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P6V4F/1/).

Comment: Or use `'%b&nbsp;%d'` to force no linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is correct, but just as another piece of information, there is a bug in 0.8.1 with the way ticks are spaced on the x-axis; less space is allocated per label than should be.  So you might want to try the latest master off GitHub, which will soon be released as 0.8.2, and see whether that helps.